# Should I use the appDelegate for all singleton style, app-level code?

Tags: ios, singleton, appdelegate

From a "good-design" perspective.  Should I use the appDelegate class for all app-level common code?  In other words, I have many things that many view controllers need to be able to do.  That means it's common functionality, not specific to a single view controller.  So the question is:  Should I house these common methods in the appDelegate?  Is that what it's for?  Should I create another separate class?

Here are a few examples of the common functionality I speak of:

1)  Play a common sound (such as error sound).

2)  Show an alert message (such as an error message).

3)  Method to validate input that should be of a specific type (decimal-numeric)

4)  Update app-level data from a web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all common functions to appDelegate class is not good idea.

1 & 2) You can create super class and all your view controller inherit it or use category.

3 & 4) You can create a normal function class to achieve. e.g. Your class name is Function and you have class method, to use it just simple call [Function validate:yourdata] return boolen value.

Comment: I like it!  Inheriting from a view controller superclass seems obvious to me now, but I especially like the Function class idea for random common functions.  I'm going to mark as correct and use your idea unless someone tells me why it's a terrible idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I think every software developer has his own personal function class which can make the programming life easier (I got one, and I always use it for every project). When time is going, your personal function class will be powerful : ) So if you find any common methods that you think you may reuse it, then just add it to your own personal function class : )

Comment: Just as comment: For 2) Common UIAlertViews... if you don't need to interact with the UIAlertViewDelegate (Each alert will have only an OK button to close the alert... and their delegate will be nil), you could have a class that extends from NSObject as in 3) with methods to show the common UIAlertViews.

Answer (score 1):

If it's data-related, then having a separate Model layer in your app makes the most sense to me.  If it's code related specifically to how you like your view controllers to behave then a common super-class or even a `UIViewController` category sounds more like the right solution.

I see the app delegate as more about setting up the basic application structure (which might include connecting the Model and Controller layers) and dealing with its life cycle.

Comment: Some good points.  I use core data objects for the data model layer.  Should I use a static method on the objects for them to update themselves from my web service?  I hadn't even thought about the category or super-class on the view controller, although it seems obvious now.  Is there an advantage to one or the other in this application?

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one correct, but you do get an upvote.  Thanks.